# Portfolio Expander width - Jquery CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been playing around with changing the way my portfolio looks and I've been struggling with getting my expander to push elements down (like google images does).

My test is here: http://chris-carpenter.co.uk/new/

I've used this as a starting point to add a filterable option for my work:
queness.com/post/14577/create-a-simple-responsive-portfolio-page-with-filtering-and-hover-effect

This is what is causing the problems. I've found ways to create the filterable portfolio, and ways to create a static portfolio that has an expanding content section but combining them is blowing my mind. I can't seem to figure it out.

At the moment this opens and pushes elements down, but the width is limited by the parent div, so anything below & to the right doesn't seem to shift.

```html
<div class="portfolio--expand is-expanded">
  <a href="#close-jump-1" class="expand__close"></a>
</div>
```

I'm now looking at inserting a content div at the end of the row clicked. Much like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/JfcAu/450/

I'm not experienced enough with JS to understand what's happening and apply it to what I have though. Could anyone help me achieve a filterable grid which has a click to expand option? 
I don't expect to retain any current styling ofcourse, since I haven't changed it at all from the original source yet, I just want the function working.

This has been hurting my brain for ages.
Useful things I've looked at:

isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

oriongunning.com/blog/thumbnail-grid-expanding-preview/

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do some width adjustment, but this:

```
#portfoliolist .portfolio {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 23%;
margin: 1%;
display: none;
float: left;  /* <-- this is taking it out of the DOM */
}
```

has a float:left - that is taking it out of the DOM - you have to remove the float:left - and then adjust width to maybe 22% or something to let the expanded content push everything out of the way.

Comment: Thanks for responding, 
I have tried this previously, it almost works but unfortunately it shoves the current row down too (see image). I'm not 100% sure that there is any way using css alone to achieve what I want with what I have. I'm not opposed to changing everything / starting over to achieve this. I'm sure I can add in the fancy hover effects after getting the click expander to work.

http://i.gyazo.com/17ec554aec7062a2ddda7bfc0a02a7c2.png

Comment: On that same style, try removing overflow:hidden... ?